# Static variable set in Activity not found in Fragment when app is resumed after being idle(when killed by android system) leading to app crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, static

I am setting the value into a static variable of custom type CustomData in my MainActivity in an asynctask. It is an intensive operation which downloads a json and sets its value in this object. Here is how i set it in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


private static CustomData paper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
    new Loadpaper().execute(this);
}

public class Loadpaper extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Activity... params) {
        paper = getNewsPaper(params[0]);
        return "success";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        setpagecount();          
        return ;
    }

public CustomData getpaperdata() {
    return paper;
}
}
```

Now in a child fragment for this activity i am using this static variable by calling getpaperdata in onAttach and onResume of the fragment.

```
paper = ((MainActivity) myActivity).getpaperdata();
```

It works fine in usual cases and even works when the app is paused(but not destroyed). But after some time of being idle if i try to resume the app. The system attempts to reload the screen as it was, but the variable paper is now null so the app crashes.

I read about this and also did some debugging and know that it is happening as the static variable is going to null when activity is killed. How do i fix it such that the fragment on resume calls these methods only when the asynctask of main activity is completed and variable value is set.

Comment: let Fragment implements interface `interface A { done(); }` ... let activity implements `interface B { registerA(A a); unregisterA(A a);}` in implementation of B use `ArrayList<A> registerdAs;` ... now in `onPostExecute` iterate `registerdAs` and call `done()` for each ... and in onAttach of fragment do `((B)getActivity).register(this)` and unregister it in `onDetach` ... of course it is basic idea ... you should also call `A.done()` in `register` method if async task finished before registration ... next step is ... chaning `done()` into `done(CustomData  data)`